# T-SQL drop multiple tables error subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below T-SQL to drop tables where their name exists in `tblCtrlTable`:

```
Declare @Cmd nvarchar(max)

select @cmd = ( 
SELECT 'IF OBJECT_ID(''' +TABLE_NAME + ''') IS NOT NULL BEGIN DROP TABLE [' + TABLE_NAME + '] END;' 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_NAME IN (SELECT [TEST_TABLE] from tblCtrlTable WHERE FieldX=1 and FieldY = 'Pass'))

print @cmd

--EXECUTE sp_executesql @cmd
```

However, I keep getting the error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Well....does your select statement return more than 1 row? I can safely say that it does. And you are trying to assign multiple rows to a scalar variable. You can't do that.

Comment: You can handle this in a cursor instead.

Comment: @scsimon don't need a cursor here. Just a dynamic sql string with more than one statement. :D

Comment: You're right i forgot it doesn't need batch terminators

Comment: If you are selecting from the meta-data (which you are), there is no need to add "if exists"  prior to each drop if your goal is to immediately execute your dynamically generated sql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way you do this. It doesn't ensure the order of values but it is super quick and easy. Not really sure why you are checking if the object_id is valid though....it can't be NULL because it is a table. And you know it is a table because you are querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES. :)

```
Declare @Cmd nvarchar(max) = '' --Notice this is initially set to an empty string.

select @cmd = @cmd + 'IF OBJECT_ID(''' +TABLE_NAME + ''') IS NOT NULL BEGIN DROP TABLE [' + TABLE_NAME + '] END;' 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_NAME IN (SELECT [TEST_TABLE] from tblCtrlTable WHERE FieldX=1 and FieldY = 'Pass')

print @cmd
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Table  variable instead of variable:

```
Declare @Cmd TABLE (QUERY nvarchar(max))

INSERT INTO @Cmd(QUERY)
SELECT
            'IF OBJECT_ID(''' + TABLE_NAME + ''') IS NOT NULL BEGIN DROP TABLE [' + TABLE_NAME + '] END;'
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE TABLE_NAME IN (SELECT
                [TEST_TABLE]
            FROM tblCtrlTable
            WHERE FieldX = 1
            AND FieldY = 'Pass')


SELECT * FROM @cmd
```